# .csv file int variable to factor in R

Tags: r, csv

I have a big .csv data set. $B1 through $B34. They are all numeric, which is fine. **But I would like the last column to be in "factor"** The values of the last column DEC consists of only 1 and 0.
How can I make the last column "factor"

```
 mydata<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
 str(mydata) 
'data.frame':   1024 obs. of  35 variables:
 $ B1   : num  90.8 113.2 100.4 144.5 131.6 ...
 $ B2   : num  0.133 0.139 0.144 0.147 0.141 ...
-----------
-----------
 $ B32  : num  0.216 0.27 0.309 0.259 0.304 ...
 $ B33  : num  0.526 0.407 0.286 0.129 0.37 ...
 $ B34  : num  4.33 5.61 4.81 7.32 6.83 ...
 $ DEC  : int  1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
```

Comment: Please provide a reproducible example (`dput()`, not `str()`).  Also, what is the delimiter of this file?

Comment: mydata$DEC <- as.factor(mydata$DEC)

Comment: dput(mydata) gives a very long output. but here is the last part of it     2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 
    2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L)), .Names = c("B1", 
"B2", "B3", "B4", "B5", "B6", "B7", "B8", "B9", "B10", "B11", 
"B12", "B13", "B14", "B15", "B16", "B17", "B18", "B19", "B20", 
"B21", "B22", "B23", "B24", "B25", "B26", "B27", "B28", "B29", 
"B30", "B31", "B32", "B33", "B34", "DEC"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-1024L))

Comment: U can dput(head(mydata,1))

Comment: Try `cf <- count.fields(file); read.table(file, header = TRUE, colClasses = c(rep("numeric", max(cf) - 1), "factor"))` where `file` is your file name

Comment: Thank you chinsoon12, "mydata$DEC <- as.factor(mydata$DEC)" worked !

Comment: delimineter is comma ,

Comment: > cf <- count.fields(file= mydata); read.table(mydata, sep=",", header = TRUE, colClasses = c(rep("numeric", max(cf) - 1), "factor"))
Error in count.fields(file = mydata) : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection   how can I solve this ?

Comment: count.fields(yourFileName, sep=",")

Comment: > mydata<-read.csv(file.choose(),header=T)
> cf <- count.fields(mydata, sep = ","); read.table(mydata, header = TRUE, colClasses = c(rep("numeric", max(cf) - 1), "factor"))
Error in count.fields(mydata, sep = ",") : 
  'file' must be a character string or connection

Comment: fname<-file.choose(); cf <- count.fields(fname,sep=","); mydata <- read.table(fname, etc etc etc

Comment: Chinsoon12 Thank you, I don't know how to give you a credit for your answer. I was going to mark your first answer as useful answer but coudn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the `as.factor()` function to convert any column to factor. For example:

```
  mydata<-read.csv("data.csv") #Read the data#
  mydata$DEC<-as.factor(mydata$DEC) #Convert the column to a factor
  class(mydata$DEC) #Just to check that it worked#
```